# Finding the perfect statline for a roleplaying game using Python

Tags: python, performance, beginner, random

I made a program for fun that tries to roll a perfect statline, i.e a statline with two groups of only 18s, for a role-playing game. I'm still a newbie in python so mainly trying to learn how to make the code more "pythonic" and efficient.

**Background and explanation:** The tabletop role-playing game pathfinder has 6 stats for each character. One of the most common ways to determine these stats are by rolling 4d6 and dropping the lowest die, thus giving a number between 3 and 18 (inclusive). For the current game we roll 4d6 drop lowest three times and place them in a group. In total we roll 6 groups. We then get to pick two groups for our character giving us our 6 stats.

Example of groups: [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18], [17, 16, 15]

Example of statline by picking two groups: 16, 17, 18, 17, 16, 15

**What I've tried:** I have tried rolling the stats in a for loop instead of calling the method 6 times in the dict. I've tried to implement numpy's randomization but it's slower when randomizing so few numbers.

This is my first question on Code review so please give me any feedback about improving my question.

```py
import random
import time

def statliner():

    # Rolls 4d6 drops lowest and returns it
    def roll4d6droplow():
        rolls = [random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6)]
        rolls.sort()
        rolls.pop(0)
        return sum(rolls)

    # Rolls an entire statline and returns it
    def rollstatline():
        statline = []
        for _ in range(6):
            group = [roll4d6droplow(), roll4d6droplow(), roll4d6droplow()]
            statline.append(group)
        return statline

    # Checks how many groups contain a perfect roll
    def checkmaxedstats(statline):
        maxgroups = 0
        for group in statline:
            if sum(group) == (18 * 3):
                maxgroups += 1
        if maxgroups >= 2:
            statline.append(True)
        return statline

    return checkmaxedstats(rollstatline())
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def getgodstatline():
        repetitions = 1
        runswithstats = []

        for _ in range(repetitions):
            runs = 0
            stats = []
            start = time.perf_counter()
            # Loop until we find a perfect statline
            while True not in stats:
                runs += 1
                stats = statliner()
                if runs % 100000 == 0:
                    stop = time.perf_counter()
                    print(f"Last 100,000 runs took {stop - start:0.2f} seconds.")
                    print("Total runs: " + f"{runs:,}")
                    start = time.perf_counter()
            runswithstats.append(f"{runs} : {stats}")

        for line in runswithstats:
            print(line)
            
    getgodstatline()
```

Comment: Wow, this is a *very* generous method of rolling stats. We've clearly come a long way from the classic "roll 3d6 for each stat and be happy with what you get".

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Until you consider that the norm in Pathfinder (and most other d20 systems these days) is actually a point-buy approach that eliminates any randomness. FWIW though, I’ve never see this type of grouping approach before though despite being a rather avid TTRPG player.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn: True, but you'll never get a stat array anywhere near as good with a standard point buy budget as this method would give you. (Well, almost never. I checked using my Python dice calculator from [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/166663) and the extended D&D 5e point-buy costs from [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/185268), and this method gives arrays that are worth 46.9 points on average (std.dev. ±9.4 points), with only a 1.3% chance of rolling an array you could buy using the standard point buy budget of 27 points or less.)

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn I have honestly never been in a game that uses point-buy. We usually just run with 4d6 drop lowest but for this campaign our DM wanted us to try something different. They wanted us to have more choices but also push us towards taking a wider spread of stats. For example taking group with a very high and a low stat in it would force some degree of extra planning and maybe open up for some interesting roleplaying.

Answer (score 9):

> I've tried to implement numpy's randomization but it's slower when randomizing so few numbers.

That's one key problem: you shouldn't be running a loop over "so few numbers". Numpy is only effective if you vectorise your code. For example, this code tries a million statlines at a time:

```
import numpy as np

LINES_PER_BLOCK = 1_000_000
GROUPS_PER_LINE = 6
SUMS_PER_GROUP = 3
ROLLS_PER_SUM = 4
DIE_SIDES = 6


rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)


def roll_statline() -> np.ndarray:
    """Rolls one block of LINES_PER_BLOCK statlines"""

    addends = rand.integers(
        size=(LINES_PER_BLOCK, GROUPS_PER_LINE, SUMS_PER_GROUP, ROLLS_PER_SUM),
        low=1, high=DIE_SIDES, endpoint=True, dtype=np.int32,
    )
    min_indices = addends.argmin(axis=3)
    min_mask = np.arange(ROLLS_PER_SUM)[
        np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :
    ] == min_indices[..., np.newaxis]
    addends[min_mask] = 0
    sums = addends.sum(axis=3, dtype=np.int32)
    return sums


def check_maxed_stats(statlines: np.ndarray, min_groups: int = 2) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Checks how many groups contain a perfect roll
    This is considered a "god" statline if at least two of the groups have sums equal to 18 * 3
    """
    is_max = np.bitwise_and.reduce(
        statlines == DIE_SIDES * (ROLLS_PER_SUM - 1),
        axis=2,
    )
    group_counts = np.count_nonzero(is_max, axis=1)

    return statlines[group_counts >= min_groups, ...]


def get_god_statline() -> np.ndarray:
    while True:
        print('.', end='')
        statlines = roll_statline()
        god_statlines = check_maxed_stats(statlines)
        if god_statlines.size:
            return god_statlines[0, ...]


def main() -> None:
    statline = get_god_statline()
    print(statline)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But much more importantly: Algorithmically your search doesn't make sense. It's analogous to generating a random number between one and ten billion, and iterating until you find one that's exactly zero. Why not just return zero in the first place?

In other words: since your dice rolls are independent, simply fill two groups with 18, and fill the other four using your random-minmask-sum.

```
import numpy as np

GROUPS_PER_LINE = 6
SUMS_PER_GROUP = 3
ROLLS_PER_SUM = 4
DIE_SIDES = 6


rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)


def roll_statline() -> np.ndarray:
    """Rolls one statline"""

    addends = rand.integers(
        size=(GROUPS_PER_LINE, SUMS_PER_GROUP, ROLLS_PER_SUM),
        low=1, high=DIE_SIDES, endpoint=True, dtype=np.int32,
    )

    min_indices = addends.argmin(axis=2)
    min_mask = np.arange(ROLLS_PER_SUM)[
        np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :
    ] == min_indices[..., np.newaxis]
    addends[min_mask] = 0

    sums = addends.sum(axis=2, dtype=np.int32)

    god_rows = rand.choice(np.arange(GROUPS_PER_LINE), size=2, replace=False)
    sums[god_rows, ...] = DIE_SIDES * (ROLLS_PER_SUM - 1)

    return sums


def main() -> None:
    print(roll_statline())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This executes in a tiny fraction of the time. Statistically, since the rolls are independent, this is equivalent (with the imperceptible difference that we assume two max-groups instead of waiting a long time for at least two max-groups).

Comment: This is most likely a great answer. The only problem is that I do not understand enough of it to apply it to my code with straight copy-pasting. I didn't even know of the concept of writing vectorised code before reading this.

Comment: If you have specific questions feel free to ask them; although extended discussion will have to be pulled into a dedicated chat room

Answer (score 7):

## Roll 4d6, drop low

Your dice-rolling procedure is both verbose and labour intensive.

This statement may be written much more concisely using list comprehension:

`rolls = [random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6)]`

could become:

`rolls = [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(4)]`

which is both shorter and clearer.  A reader can immediately tell a die is being rolled 4 times, instead of having to scan the statement and count the number of terms in the list.

As pointed out by Caridorc, `rolls.sort(); rolls.pop(0); return sum(rolls)` can be replaced with `return sum(rolls) - min(rolls)`.  This is clearer, since it is now obvious the lowest value is being excluded from the sum. It is also much faster, since the no \$N \log N\$ sort operation is required.  Given you are performing this operation millions of times, this will be significant.

```
def roll_4d6_drop_low():
    rolls = [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(4)]
    return sum(rolls) - min(rolls)
```

Still, this method requires 4 random numbers to be generated, summed, a minimum found, and a subtraction ... done millions of times.  We can do better.

---

There is exactly one way of rolling a `3`: getting a `1` from all four dice.  There are 21 ways of getting an `18`: rolling four sixes, and rolling three sixes with the first, second, third and fourth die rolling a one through five.  Similarly, we can count or compute the ways of rolling the other possible outcomes:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import product

d6 = range(1, 6 + 1)
freq = Counter(sum(rolls) - min(rolls) for rolls in product(d6, repeat=4))
```

After executing this code, `freq.items()` will contain the values `(3, 1), (4, 4), (5, 10), (6, 21), (7, 38), (8, 62), (9, 91), (10, 122), (11, 148), (12, 167), (13, 172), (14, 160), (15, 131), (16, 94), (17, 54), (18, 21)`, showing a `3` will occur 1 way, through an `18` occurring 21 times in the \$6^4\$ different rolls.

Using `random.choices()` with this distribution, we can generate a random "4d6 drop lowest" roll value using a single random number.

```
from random import choices

roll_4d6, = choices(list(freq), freq.values())
```

Since `choices()` internally needs the cumulative distribution, we can pre-compute that, instead of forcing `choices()` to recompute it every time.

```
from itertools import accumulate

population = list(freq)
cum_weights = list(accumulate(freq.values()))

roll_4d6, = choices(population, cum_weights=cum_weights)
```

## Roll Stat Line

You aren't rolling "4d6 drop one" in isolation.  You are rolling it 18 times to get 6 groups of 3 individual "4d6 drop one" rolls.  The `choices` function allows you to efficiently generate an entire list of random values following the given distribution all at once.

```
rolls = choices(population, cum_weights=cum_weights, k=18)
```

Since we want those 18 values as 6 groups of 3, we need to group every three values together.  We can use the `grouper()` function for this,

```
from more_itertools import grouper

groups = grouper(rolls, 3)
```

Since `grouper(...)` returns an iterator, it would need to be converted to a `list(...)` if you want to examine it or uses the values from it more than once.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import product, accumulate
from random import choices
from more_itertools import grouper

D6 = range(1, 6 + 1)
FREQ = Counter(sum(rolls) - min(rolls) for rolls in product(D6, repeat=4))
POPULATION = list(FREQ)
CUM_WEIGHTS = list(accumulate(FREQ.values()))

def roll_stat_line():
    rolls = choices(POPULATION, cum_weights=CUM_WEIGHTS, k=18)
    return list(grouper(rolls, 3))
```

## Perfect roll groups

Your code hard codes a "perfect group" as `(18 * 3)`.  That is an unlikely occurrence, and you are looking for it to happen twice.  Let's be a little more flexible for now.  We can tighten up the requirements later, after testing easier criteria.

Three 18's is perfect.  Three 17's is pretty darn good.  Is it better, worse or similar to 16, 17, 18?

We can define "good" groups with predicate functions.  For example:

```
def good_group(rolls):
    return sum(rolls) >= 35

def great_group(rolls):
    return all(roll >= 15 for roll in rolls)

def perfect_group(rolls):
    return all(roll == 18 for roll in rolls)
```

For example:

```
>>> good_group([17, 12, 16])
True
>>> great_group([17, 12, 16])
False
```

Now, instead of `check_maxed_stats`, let's instead count the number of passing groups:

```
def count_stat_groups(stat_line, predicate):
    return sum(predicate(group) for group in stat_line)
```

Again, testing this:

```
>>> stat_line = [(13, 17, 10), (12, 11, 10), (13, 15, 11), (14, 15, 10), (15, 17, 15), (10, 11, 12)]
>>> count_stat_groups(stat_line, good_group)
4
>>> count_stat_groups(stat_line, great_group)
1
>>> count_stat_groups(stat_line, perfect_group)
0
```

There were four "good groups" in that stat line, one "great group", but no perfect groups.

## Searching

With the above framework, we can now add searching for god-like stat lines:

```
from time import perf_counter

def fantastic_group(rolls):
    return sum(rolls) >= 52

def generate_stat_group(predicate):
    found = False
    while not found:
        start = perf_counter()
        for _ in range(100_000):
            stat_line = roll_stat_line()
            value = count_stat_groups(stat_line, predicate)
            if value >= 2:
                found = True
                break
        else:
            stop = perf_counter()
            print(f"Last 100,000 runs took {stop - start:0.2f} seconds.")
            
    stop = perf_counter()
    print(f"Last batch took {stop - start:0.2f} seconds.")
    print(*stat_line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    generate_stat_group(fantastic_group)
```

This gives me:

```
Last 100,000 runs took 0.68 seconds.
Last 100,000 runs took 0.68 seconds.
Last 100,000 runs took 0.67 seconds.
Last 100,000 runs took 0.68 seconds.
Last 100,000 runs took 0.73 seconds.
Last batch took 0.20 seconds.
(7, 11, 14) (13, 12, 7) (17, 18, 17) (14, 13, 11) (17, 18, 17) (10, 12, 15)
```

Searching for the `perfect_group` is a simple modification, but I'm not going to wait for it to complete.

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to Code Review, first of all it is great that you are dividing your code into functions, it makes it so much easier to understand and improve.

#### Standard return value

This function is extremely weird:

```
def checkmaxedstats(statline):
    maxgroups = 0
    for group in statline:
        if sum(group) == (18 * 3):
            maxgroups += 1
    if maxgroups >= 2:
        statline.append(True)
    return statline
```

So if the `statline` respects a certain condition you add `True` to the end of it and return it. I suggest that you reorganize the logic of the program to have the function output only `True` or `False` instead of a changed list or None, this brings us to the second point:

#### Avoid nesting functions

You can define your functions separately and then call them as needed, there is no need to define them all into a single function.

#### Small readability improvement

This is only a small point with respect to the ones before but you can rewrite:

```
# Rolls 4d6 drops lowest and returns it
def roll4d6droplow():
    rolls = [random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6)]
    rolls.sort()
    rolls.pop(0)
    return sum(rolls)
```

as:

```
# Rolls 4d6 drops lowest and returns it
def roll4d6droplow():
    rolls = [random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6)]
    return sum(rolls) - min(rolls)
```

To make it simpler to understand.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, a slightly shorter way to write `rolls` would be: `rolls=random.choices(range(1,6),k=4)`. This would also generalize more nicely to a `rolld6_droplow(N=4)` or even `roll(dice=4,sides=6,drop_low=True)` function.

Comment: @Tyberius After using Python for years I never knew about the existence of `random.choices`, thanks for the tip

Comment: I didn't realize until recently, but I figured there had to be a convenience function for generating more "rolls". It looks like it was only added in Python3.6, so that might explain why you hadn't seen it before.